# A way to find location with GPS turned off

Tags: android, ios, gps, react-native

When developing mobile application using React Native, we need to get user's location. There might arise a possible case that user has GPS turned off. Is there a way to find an approximate location using React Native? When GPS is off I cannot access coordinates.

For example, in Android manifest there's `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and that would probably be the thing I want to get in React Native app.

Comment: For iOS there is only the `CLLocationManager` which use many different techniques to get the users location. But if the user turned off the location services there is not way to get the location, not by cellular, wifi or GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally doable on both Android and iOS. There is an API in React Native
that enables this:
[Official React Native Geolocation Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply. `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`  works when GPS enabled. Without GPS `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is used, isn't it true?